# Can't use manage.py when ENGINE is set to postgresql_psycopg2

Tags: django, postgresql

I have an application written in django which I'm trying to run. Here's a snippet from the configuration:

```
elif STAGE == 'TEST':
    DEBUG = False
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'username',
            'USER': 'dbname',
            'PASSWORD': 'passwd',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
        }
    }
else:
    DEBUG = True
    REGISTRATION_ENABLED = True
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../location'
                if STAGE == 'STAGING'
                else 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

When I set STAGE to TEST I can't use manage.py at all since any attempt at running it (even ./manage.py with **no arguments** gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project_location/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ELECT "auth_group"."id", "auth_group"."name" FROM "auth_grou...
```

now, when I set STAGE to anything but TEST it works flawlessly, but doesn't use postgres which I want it to use. Postgres is installed, I created the database and I can log in to it using the username and password.
What's the problem here and how can I fix it?

Comment: You haven't run the migrations.

Comment: I can't run manage.py at all, how am I supposed to run the migrations?

Comment: Then something is causing a query at startup time. You should show the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out there was an error in the application. It was programmed to catch OperationalError which is thrown for sqlite but ProgrammingError which is thrown for postgresql wasn't being caught. If someone is interested there's a github issue which describes the problem more in depth:
https://github.com/jazzband/django-sortedm2m/issues/31